# javascript: using settimeout in a for loop to show text at regular intervals

Tags: javascript

I want to show 3 lines at regular intervals(one second),here's the code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showText()
    {
        var itemlist = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
        function additem(index) {
            setTimeout(function(){itemlist[index].setAttribute("style", "display:block;");}, 1000);
        }
        for(var i=0;i<itemlist.length;++i) {
            additem(i);
        } 
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="show" onClick="showText()">
        <div class="test" style="display:none">first</div>
        <div class="test" style="display:none">second</div>
        <div class="test" style="display:none">third</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But the result is: when I click the show button,a second later,
all three div block appear together.I was expecting they will be displayed one by one with an interval of one second.

How can I fix this? Hope for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling all of them at the same time.  Using just `line1` for clarity.

```
setTimeout(line1, 1000);
setTimeout(line2, 1000);
setTimeout(line3, 1000);
```

They don't "stack".  All three functions will run in 1 second.

You have two options.  Option 1:

```
setTimeout(line1, (1 + index) * 1000);
setTimeout(line2, (1 + index) * 1000);
setTimeout(line3, (1 + index) * 1000);
```

This will cause them to timeout one after another.

The other option is making the timeout call the next one:

```
var index = 0;
function showNextLine() {
    // show line index
    index++;
    if (index < 3) {
       setTimeout(showNextLine, 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout(showNextLine, 1000);
```

This way they "chain" like you might be expecting.

There are other variations, and you could even use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`.

Comment: so the problem is that the when you click the button you call setTimeout 3 times and all those setTimeouts delays are 1 second? your solution is to dynamically change each of the times?  your increasing the time for delay by 1 second for every element

Comment: Correct.  They all delay for 1 second from **now**, so if you want them spaced apart, you can add a larger delay to each one in sequence.  But note that if the system was busy, it's possible they might still fire all at once that way... chaining would prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a global variable
- Use setInterval function
- increment count every time when setInterval executes
- start again from the start if it reaches last (if diff. b/w no. divs and count is less than 1)
- fade out all divs except the current one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    showIframe(count);
     count++;
    if (($('.wall-display').length - count) < 1) {
                    count = 0;
                }
  }, 1000);
  function showIframe(count) {
    $('.wall-display').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#frame' + count).fadeIn('fast');
  }
  
  
});
```

```css
.wall-display:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wall-display" id='frame0'>I'm first text</div>
<div class="wall-display" id='frame1'>I'm second text</div>
<div class="wall-display" id='frame2'>I'm third text</div>
```